# How to replace \not by \centernot?

Tags: renewcommand

I noticed that LaTeX places the slash created by `\not` weirdly, e.g. in `\not\ni`.

Using `\centernot` from package `centernot` looks nice, but for reasons outside of this scope I have no control over the source, but still want to change the output.

Usually, in this situation, I'd do `\renewcommand*{\not}{\centernot}`, but this results in a lot of errors, maybe because `\centernot` uses `\not` internally.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a weird positioning also with `\not\in` (at least with the Computer Modern fonts) and from the dawn of time TeX provides the command `\notin`. In LaTeX it's the same as in plain TeX, only with the command made robust. You find it in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\notin{\mathrel{\m@th\mathpalette\c@ncel\in}}
\def\c@ncel#1#2{\m@th\ooalign{$\hfil#1\mkern1mu/\hfil$\crcr$#1#2$}}
```

However, `\centernot\in` is not optimal anyway. Indeed, the slash used for `\notin` isn't `\not`, but a simple `/`.

It's easy to supplement a command `\notni`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot} % for the comparison

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\notni{\mathrel{\m@th\mathpalette\c@ncel\ni}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Output with \verb|\notni|  & $x\notni X$ \\
Output with \verb|\not\ni| & $x\not\ni X$ \\
Output with \verb|\centernot\ni| & $x\centernot\ni X$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You see that even replacing `\not` with `\centernot` the result would not be optimal. Just for comparison, here's the same table with `in` instead of `ni`:

[image]

You can get the best out of both worlds by using an old trick (which is also used by `unicode-math`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot} % for the comparison

\NewCommandCopy{\standardnot}{\not}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makenot}{mm}
 {
  % #1 = symbol to negate, #2 = replacement
  \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand{not\cs_to_str:N #1 } {} { #2 }
 }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\not}{m}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { not\cs_to_str:N #1 }
   {
    \group_begin:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \not \standardnot % to keep centernot happy
    \use:c { not\cs_to_str:N #1 }
    \group_end:
   }
   {
    \standardnot#1
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\makenot{\ni}{\mathrel{\m@th\mathpalette\c@ncel\ni}}
\makeatother

\makenot{\to}{\centernot\to}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Output with \verb|\notni|  & $x\notni X$ \\
Output with \verb|\not\ni| & $x\not\ni X$ \\
Output with \verb|\not\to| & $A\not\to B$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

With `\makenot{<symbol>}{<replacement>}` you decide what `\not<symbol>` should stand for. With this code, `\not\ni` and `\notni` are equivalent.

[image]

What's the idea? First I alias `\not` in order to still have the original available. Then I redefine `\not` with an argument, which should be a control sequence.

Assuming the call is `\not\foo`, I check whether the control sequence `\notfoo` is defined and, in this case, use it. Otherwise the standard `\not` is used.

For instance `\not\in` would be transformed into `\notin` out of the box. We can also use `\makenot` to define new `\not<symbol>` commands. If we do

```
\makenot\foo{whatever}
```

the command `\notfoo` would be defined to mean `whatever`. In the example code, `\notni` is defined as suggested in the first part of the answer. Instead `\notto` is defined via `\makenot\to{\centernot\to}`.

There is a safety measure in that the usage of `\notfoo` is enclosed between `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:`, so `\not` can be redefined to the original meaning inside this group so to make `\centernot` happy (it uses `\not` with its original meaning).

Another possible usage is

```
\makenot{\mid}{\nmid}
```

so `\not\mid` would produce the better symbol `\nmid`; note that neither `\not\mid` (with the standard `\not`) nor `\centernot\mid` produce a nice result (big understatement).

The key is `\cs_to_str:N` that strips off the backslash leaving just the control sequence name.

Comment: interesting, but doesnt meet the premise of my question. i need to be able to make code that already contains `\not` create different output. i am "happy enough" with the way `\centernot` looks, i dont want to optimize every occurrence individually.

Comment: @peter I disagree: `\centernot\ni` is really awful. Anyway, you can do as you like using the code I added.

Comment: thanks, i like that code. i just hope i'll be able to understand it eventually.

Comment: @peter I added a description

Comment: wow, that is way smarter than i expected. i'll accept this answer as superior since it doesnt require a package.

Answer (score 2):

The negated "contains" character is defined in Unicode as character number hex 220c "DOES NOT CONTAIN AS MEMBER" U+220C (∌)  and is available in the `unicode-math` package  as `\nni` and also in some fonts for pdflatex, notably `stix2`. Using this there is no need to position a slash over the base symbol at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}

$ x \in Y \quad Y \ni x$


$ x \notin Y \quad Y \nni x$

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Negated contains is Unicode U+220C"* (seems incomprehensible)? Do you mean *"Negated is contained in Unicode U+220C"*? Or something else?

Comment: that would only help in my situation if i were able to make `\not\ni` produce that character. also wont that stix2 package change the look of every single character in my document?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I mean the Unicode standard includes this negated character in position hex 220C as a single character not as a combination of two symbols.

Comment: @peter using stix2 might change every character or might not, Since you gave no indication at all in your question about the fonts you are using, I can't say. stix2 was just an example here, you can read the answer as "some font sets contain this character as a ready made glyph"  whether that applies to the fonts you are using, only you can  know.

Comment: @PeterMortensen “negated contains” is the name of the character U+220C.

Comment: @L.F. yes I'll re-arrage the sentnce to use a less compressed form of the English

Comment: @PeterMortensen I edited it a bit I hope it's clearer now.